# Expand parent div width to fit children divs, horizontal scroll website

Tags: html, expand

I am making a horizontal scroll gallery style website, similar to this one:
http://ericryananderson.com/book_2

I have a parent div, and within that div are child divs for each individual item of the gallery.

Since I will not know how many items will be in the gallery/will change over time, how do I make the parent div size automatically in such a way that the gallery items remain on the same single line, allowing contents to overflow the width of the screen, again like in the site I have referenced above.

It currently only behaves the way I want to if I manually set the width.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent-gallery-div">
    <div class="gallery-item"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.parent-gallery-div {
   height: 500px;
   float: left;
   margin-top: 40px;
}

.gallery-item {
   height: 420px;
   float: left;
   margin-right: 20px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to achieve this by using jScrollPane Plugin http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/
Here is an example:
http://longinstudio.pl/realizacje/reklama%20zewnetrzna

Usage is relatively simple and it looks better than http://ericryananderson.com solution.
(f.e it is possible to control scroll appearance and animation effects)

Comment: My own site that I am working on is better, simpler and more functional than the example I gave, and you can scroll it horizontally using the mousewheel. 

Sorry, I do not think I need to use jquery to achieve what I want, CSS should be able to handle it.

http://www.lethalmonk6.byethost24.com/seamscape.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the height as auto.

try this code

```
<div class="parent-gallery-div">
    <div class="gallery-item"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item"></div>
    <div class="gallery-item"></div>
    ...
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

and remove the height property for the "parent-gallery-div"

Comment: I want the height to remain constant, and the content to continue on the same line horizontally, thus why I need the div width to expand dynamically. Does this do that?