# Expanding parent div to child size when larger than page width

Tags: css, html

A parent div must completely contain the contents to a child div.  Due to an odd circumstance, that child div might be wider than the page view itself.  Problem being, the parent div seems to always be limited to the page width, no matter what it contains.

http://jsfiddle.net/e5Lkq/1/

contains:

```
<div class="outer clearfix">
    <div class="inner">Oversized content here.</div>
</div>

.inner{
    background-color:red;
    height:50px;
    width:1800px;
}

.outer{
    border:5px solid blue;
    /* overflow:hidden; */
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

In this example, I need the outer div (with the blue border) to expand around the child's contents.

I've come across this problem before - something about a quirky rendering of the "body" style - but I've been unable to locate similar questions again this time.   Setting overflow to hidden for the parent just cuts off the child element.  I could always throw in a js to to resize after loading, but I'd rather avoid this.  Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Jeremy

PS I see this similar item, but the answer is jquery.  This might just have to be the way of it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360465/expand-parent-div-width-to-fit-children-divs-horzontal-scroll-website

Comment: You do have to give people some time (to possibly sleep even). rushing them won't make them pick you sooner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is similar to a shrink-wrap. http://jsfiddle.net/e5Lkq/2/

```
.outer { display: table }
```

To get old IE support, you can use `inline-block` (on a by-default inline element) inside a `block` container. See [this](http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/CSS-Shrink-Wrap) and [this](http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) (if you're really concerned about support). But I *strongly encourage* you to drop support (if you can). Is the extra 8% worth the effort? Also note that the percentages are different depending on the site.

Comment: Unfortunately, table isn't fully used yet; we need to be able to support older browsers as we have a less tech heavy clientele.

Comment: Just FYI, 90% support still: http://caniuse.com/css-table. Not enough for an application used worldwide yet.  But I appreciate the thought.

Comment: Our particular product supports those in less developed areas and countries and the percentage of IE8 use is actually much higher than 8%. And when you're talking large companies, 8% is definitely worth it either way.

Both the examples use overflow or other methods that don't work once the content itself is stretched horizontally larger than the page.  The float:left question below does technically answer the question correctly, though it doesn't work in all cases (and doesn't in my real-life case, for other reasons).  I'm going to end up using this idea plus js for <=IE8

Answer (score 1):

floating the parent appears to work:

```
.outer{
    border:5px solid blue;
    float:left;

}
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/n6WLG/

Comment: Yeah, but it could interfere with other floats.